# height of colorbar in subplot (matplotlib)

Tags: matplotlib

We can change the height and width and position of colorbar by using :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
im = ax.imshow(np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10)))

c = plt.colorbar(im, cax = fig.add_axes([0.78, 0.5, 0.03, 0.38]))
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50436731/height-of-colorbar-matplotlib),

I am going to use this in subplots with [add_axes and transorm](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html):

[image]

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
im0 = axs[0].imshow(np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10)), cmap='afmhot')
c = plt.colorbar(im0, cax=fig.add_axes([0.45, 0.52, 0.03, 0.2],
                                       transform=axs[0].transAxes))
# transform=axs[0].transAxes) does not make any difference

im1 = axs[1].imshow(np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10)), cmap='afmhot_r')
c = plt.colorbar(im1, cax=fig.add_axes([0.87, 0.52, 0.03, 0.2]))
```

I am going to use transform (transAxes) option to set the location from axes not the figure, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, from the [`add_axes`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes) documentation,

> rect : sequence of float
>     The dimensions [left, bottom, width, height] of the new axes. **All quantities are in 
>     fractions of figure width and height**.

This is the reason your code doesn't work.

You may instead use an [`inset_axes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html).

> `inset_axes(self, bounds, transform=None, ...)`
>
> `bounds` : [x0, y0, width, height]
>     Lower-left corner of inset axes, and its width and height.
>
> `transform` : Transform
>     Defaults to ax.transAxes, i.e. the units of rect are in axes-relative coordinates.

Here the bounds default to units of axes coordinates, but can be changed if needed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10)))

cax = ax.inset_axes([0.78, 0.5, 0.03, 0.38])
cb = fig.colorbar(im, cax = cax)

plt.show()
```

An alternative to the above is to use `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.inset_axes`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10)))

cax = inset_axes(ax, "100%", "100%", bbox_to_anchor=[0.78, 0.5, 0.03, 0.38],
                 bbox_transform=ax.transAxes, borderpad=0)
cb = fig.colorbar(im, cax = cax)

plt.show()
```

Comment: `ax.inset_axes` only work with python 3? I get this error: `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'inset_axes'`

Comment: Yep, I added an alternative.