# Change colorbar size in matplotlib after creation

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have some code that looks like this (where `heatmap` is a wrapper on seaborn's `sns.heatmap` that returns the same thing)

```
def binary_heatmap(
    X, colors=["white", "black"], colorbar_ticklabels=["No Edge", "Edge"], outline=False, **kwargs
):
    cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(colors)
    plot = heatmap(X, center=None, cmap=cmap, **kwargs)
    colorbar = plot.collections[0].colorbar
    cbar = kwargs.setdefault("cbar", True)
    if cbar:
        colorbar.set_ticks([0.25, 0.75])
        colorbar.set_ticklabels(colorbar_ticklabels)
        colorbar.ax.set_frame_on(True)
    if outline:
        sns.despine(top=False, bottom=False, left=False, right=False)
        
    return plot

binary_heatmap(averaged, title="Averaged Brain Network", outline=True);
```

With some data that I generated before, this returns a figure that looks like this:

[image]

I want to change the colorbar so that it looks more like a figure legend. Specifically, I just want to scale its vertical size down to maybe 1/5 of what it is now. I thought this would be pretty straightforward, but after 30 minutes of googling and diving into matplotlib's deep magic, I'm no closer to finding a simple solution.

I'm assuming that I want to change the `colorbar.ax` in some way, but nothing that I've found seems to do exactly what I want.

Does anybody have a solution? I found other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50436731/height-of-colorbar-matplotlib), but everything else I've found so far works by calling `plt.colorbar` to make a new colorbar, rather than changing the size of an existing one.

I suppose I could make a new colorbar, but it seems like there should be an easy way to just adjust an existing one, right?

Comment: You can pass kwargs to seaboard's heat map that control the size of the colorbar while you make it.  That is preferable if you are going to rely on any automatic resizing of axes etc.  https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html

Comment: For example, you might use `sns.heatmap(..., cbar_kws={'shrink':0.5}`). See [colorbar](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html) for more properties that can be changed.